# PHP and Visual Basic 2008 Conversion

Tags: php, vb.net

I need help converting this into PHP:

```
Public Function Encrypt(ByVal text As String) As String
        Dim charSet1 As String, charSet2 As String, i As Long
        Dim pos As Long, encryptedChar, encryptedText
        charSet1 = " ?!@#$%^&*()_+|0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,-~ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ¿¡²³ÀÁÂÃÄÅÒÓÔÕÖÙÛÜàáâãäåØ¶§Ú¥"
        charSet2 = " ¿¡@#$%^&*()_+|01²³456789ÀbÁdÂÃghÄjklmÅÒÓqÔÕÖÙvwÛÜz.,-~AàáâãFGHäJKåMNØ¶QR§TÚVWX¥Z?!23acefinoprstuxyBCDEILOPSUY"
        For i = 1 To Len(text)
            pos = InStr(charSet1, Mid(text, i, 1))
            If pos > 0 Then
                encryptedChar = Mid(charSet2, pos, 1)
                encryptedText = encryptedText + encryptedChar
            Else
                encryptedText = encryptedText + Mid(text, i, 1)
            End If
        Next
        Encrypt = encryptedText
    End Function
```

FROM VISUAL BASIC TO PHP...

I'm making a text to hash thing like presented above but in PHP for my website..  The code above is home-made so its nothing like MD5 or SHA1. But if you guys do know a way to encrypt and decrypt MD5 in Visual basic 2008 please show me! (this must also work for PHP).

Comment: MD5 is a hash function that produces a 128-bit number from an arbitrary-length message. It's impossible to "decrypt" the original message from the hash value, however you can find a set of messages that hash to the same value (hash collisions), one of which will be the original message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than convert the above subroutine to PHP, here is a subroutine to convert a string to its MD5 Hash in VB.NET:

```
Function getMD5Hash(ByVal strToHash As String) As String

    Dim md5Obj As New Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider

    Dim bytesToHash() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToHash)

    bytesToHash = md5Obj.ComputeHash(bytesToHash)

    Dim strResult As String = ""

    For Each b As Byte In bytesToHash

        strResult += b.ToString("x2")

    Next

    Return strResult

End Function
```

in PHP you can use the md5 function:

```
$hashedString = md5(strToHash);
```

By it's nature as a hash, you cannot decrypt a hash, you can only hash it and compare it to a stored hash.

Of course, I have to link to the Coding Horror post on Rainbow Tables and salting your hashes:

[**Coding Horror**: Rainbow Hash Cracking](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000949.html)